# Converter arquivo .raw para arquivo .mp3 ou outro formato de áudio

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo, conversão

Tenho uma aplicação que faz gravações de áudio e armazena em um servidor.
Eu preciso que esses arquivos sejam convertidos da extensão .raw para qualquer formato de áudio, de preferencia pra extensão .mp3, para que seja efetuado o download para o computador do cliente.

Obs.: Minha aplicação é desenvolvida em JAVA Desktop.

Comment: É a sua própria aplicação que grava o áudio?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT! O que você já tentou? dê uma lida neste link para melhorar a qualidade da tua pergunta: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar você vai precisar descobrir quantos quadros por segundo (sample rate) o seu áudio foi gerado e qual a devida resolução de amostra (bit rate), sabendo estes valores você poderá desenvolver um algoritmo para encodar arquivos ".RAW" para qualquer outro tipo, desde que você conheça os passos necessários para codificar para a extensão de áudio de interesse,  essa não é uma tarefa simples, deve existir alguma classe pronta que execute codificação mas nunca procurei por nada assim em Java, o algoritmo para codificar arquivos de raw para wav não é muito complexo...

O mais simples a se fazer é utilizar algum software de conversão que aceite entradas por linha de comando para efetuar a conversão, eu recomendo o [sox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/)

Aqui um exemplo de como utilizar:

```
sox -r 8000 –bits 16 –encoding signed-integer –endian big -t raw original.RAW convertido.wav
```

Este exemplo efetua conversão de um arquivo raw gravado em 16 bits e sampleado a 8000 hertz para a extensão ".wav"

Comment: No caso seria .mp3 na pergunta. Claro que dependendo do programa usado, é só ajuste, mas acho que uma editadinha pra um exemplo com mp3 ajudaria.